# minimum value of floor sum for three positive numbers

Tags: inequality

> If $p,q,r$ are three positive real number. Then find Minimum  of
> $\displaystyle \left\lfloor \frac{p+q}{r}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{q+r}{p}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{r+p}{q}\right\rfloor $

What I try  : Using $\displaystyle \lfloor x\rfloor> x-1$

Then $\displaystyle \left\lfloor \frac{p+q}{r}\right\rfloor \geq \frac{p+q}{r}-1$

$\displaystyle \sum_{\text{Cyclic}}\left\lfloor \frac{p+q}{r}\right\rfloor \geq \bigg(\frac{p+q}{r}+\frac{q+r}{p}+\frac{r+p}{q}\bigg)-3=6-3=3$

$\left(\text{Above } \displaystyle \frac{p}{r}+\frac{r}{p}+\frac{q}{r}+\frac{r}{q}+\frac{r}{p}+\frac{p}{r}\geq 6\right)$

But answer given is $4$

How do I solve it , Help me

Comment: Not clear why you think that $\frac {p+q}r+\frac {q+r}p+\frac {r+p}q=6$.  In any case, I would rewrite in terms of $\frac Np, \frac Nq, \frac Nr$  where $N=p+q+r$ and argue that the minimum must come when these three fractions are very nearly equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you have a strict inequality like you stated at the start, so the expression cannot be exactly 3. (Including lulu's comment,) Thus, we have

$$\lfloor \frac{p+q}{r}\rfloor +\lfloor \frac{q+r}{p}\rfloor +\lfloor \frac{r+p}{q}\rfloor > \bigg(\frac{p+q}{r}+\frac{q+r}{p}+\frac{r+p}{q}\bigg)-3 \geq 6-3=3.$$

Since the expression is an integer, it has a lower bound of 4.
It remains to show that this lower bound can be achieved, in order to conclude that the minimum is indeed 4.

Comment: Thanks Calvin Lin , We can achieve it at $p=9,q=11$ and $r=11$

Answer (score 2):

By defining $f(p,q,r)= \lfloor \frac{p+q}{r}\rfloor +\lfloor \frac{q+r}{p}\rfloor +\lfloor \frac{r+p}{q}\rfloor$ and $ \frac{p+q}{r}=k$, it is obvious that $f(p,q,r)=f(ap,aq,ar)$ for $a>0$. So, without loss pf generality, we assume $r=1$ and we seek to find the minimum of $g(p,q)=\lfloor p+q\rfloor +\lfloor \frac{q+1}{p}\rfloor +\lfloor \frac{1+p}{q}\rfloor$ for $p>0$ and $q>0$.

We know
$$
g(p,q){=\lfloor p+q\rfloor +\lfloor \frac{q+1}{p}\rfloor +\lfloor \frac{1+p}{q}\rfloor
\\>
p+q-1 + \frac{q+1}{p} -1+ \frac{1+p}{q}-1
\\=p+\frac{1}{p}+q+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{q}{p}+\frac{p}{q}-3
\ge 3,
}
$$
or $g(p,q)\ge 4$, since $g(p,q)$ is always an integer. Also, $g(p,p)=\lfloor 2p\rfloor+2\lfloor \frac{1}{p}\rfloor+2$. Hence
$g(1.25)=\lfloor 2.5\rfloor+2\lfloor 0.8\rfloor+2=4$. Therefore, the infimum is achievable and the proof is complete $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Done accordingly.